# What does "energy method" mean in proving the regularity of elliptic equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question

At the end of the section of regularity regarding the elliptic equations (Chapter 6.3), Evans makes a comment in his *Partial Differential Equations*:

> [image]

Would anybody explain what "energy" method means here? A quick search on Google returns that it might be related to the *[calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations)*. But I don't see any calculus of variations in the mentioned section above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is the unknown of a PDE, expressions like $\int_U|u|^2$ and $\int_U|\nabla u|^2$ are usually interpreted in terms of energies related to the physical problem behind the PDE. Methods that involve estimates on that type of integrals are called *energy methods*. Historically, this may come from Hilbert's solution to the Dirichlet problem, which consisted in minimizing the integral $\int_U|\nabla u|^2$.